# WPF DataGrid Binding - Which is best?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I am fairly new to WPF and MVVM.

I see that a DataGrid can be bound to a CollectionViewSource or an ObservableCollection or a DataSet.

What is the significance of using one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CollectionViewSource` is the XAML equivalent (can be instanciated in XAML) for [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx), which provides functionality for grouping, sorting, filtering, and navigating in any data collection. If you want to provide any of these features in the view (XAML) *only* and do not want to do this in the viewmodel, use a `CollectionViewSource` else use the `ObservableCollection` or `CollectionView` in your viewmodel. Use a `DataSet`when you have your data already in that form and do not want to go through the hassle of creating a viewmodel.

I mostly use the `ObservableCollection` in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you using DataSet. You could sort, group and filter data using CollectionViewSource.

Comment: Even if I agree, some arguments are missing here !

Comment: @JYL: I did not do a lot of research to answer this question.  I just answered what I remember.